# AWS Elasticsearch Service - How to authenticate ES endpoint with AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, elasticsearch, amazon-cognito, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm creating a search service on AWS Elasticsearch and it's only for internal users, so I have to authenticate the users through a Cognito User Pool.

I found the an article on AWS to **Configuring Amazon Cognito authentication for Kibana** in here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-cognito-auth.html. But it's only for Kibana, I still can't access the Search Endpoint to do searching.

Please help to advise on how to use the AWS Elastic Search API with the auth token from Cognito.

Thanks